# How does the given automated display file refresh work?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I took an example from
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1010188

I realized that 'DFRWTR *NO' is not necessary. Why?

KNUM 1 was converted to MAXDEV(*FILE) in rpgle. How does it contribute to the functionality? (the program compiles, but it doesn't refresh without it)

Regarding 'READ TIMED', why can't we use the record format to read?
(it's an externally described file, and it compiles, but doesn't refresh)

Thanks a lot
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DFRWRT(*YES) (the default for CRTDSPF) means that IBM i will accept the display buffer from the HLL program and immediately return control to the HLL program.  *In a second process, it will actually send the buffer to the terminal.* **EDIT**: There's no second process; the screen is sent at the next READ.  See Charles' comment. **END EDIT**  So with DFRWRT(*YES) it is possible for the program to continue on before the user has seen the display.  For this example that's irrelevant because the very next operation is a READ, so the program will stop there and wait for input.

The design here is called 'Read from Invited Devices' and the automatic refresh is about the only surviving use of the technique.  Originally, read from invited was intended for one program - one job - to control multiple terminals.  The idea was to write a screen to multiple display devices and INVITE them all to respond when ready.  The first one to respond would satisfy the READ and the program would continue.  If none of the devices responded within the WAITRCD() interval, the INVITE would expire (as an I/O error) and the program would get control - presumably to re-send updated information to the various terminals.

That's the reason we tell RPG that there are multiple devices - MAXDEV(*FILE) and also why we READ from the file but WRITE to the record format.  Imagine an arrangement where the multiple devices are arranged in a boss - worker relationship.  Your program would send the boss device the BOSS record format and all the worker devices would get the WORKER record format.  But you don't want to only wait for the boss to respond; you need to get input from everyone.  So you READ the file.

More information can be found in the [Application Display Programming](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/rzakc/sc415715.pdf) manual.  Knowledge Center > Programming > Device > Application Display Programming

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is the book I was looking for. In this case there's only one record format, so it looks more like a rule than a reason. From the book pg 69: "A record format cannot be specified on the read-from-invited-devices operation. The record format returned from a display is the same as the last record format written to the display station." FYI for others: pg 75, 83, 249. Could you please recommend some material regarding the mechanism of reading the file instead of the record?

Comment: I found this: http://rpg400-l.midrange.narkive.com/E2wBSSoT/reading-file-record-format

Comment: Actually with DFRWRT(*YES), the screen isn't sent by a "2nd process".  Instead the screen is not sent till a READ is done.  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/cl/crtdspf.htm?lang=en  "Specifies that the writing of data is delayed until it is written out with other data when a read request is made."

Comment: I couldn't find the canonical reference. Thanks for the better explanation Charles.

Comment: from http://rpg400-l.midrange.narkive.com/E2wBSSoT/reading-file-record-format: Scott Klement 12 years ago
Reading using the file's name will read the next record from that file,
no matter what record format it happens to be.
Reading using the record format name will read the next record of the
format name that you've specified.
If the file has only one record format, they will behave exactly the
same way.
So if it's true, the logic of the worker and boss record formats is not relevant. What do you think?

Comment: READ INVITED is different to READ from a disk file. The boss / worker scenario is only to show how the design was implemented 30 years ago. That design has given us three rules: 1) WAITRCD() 2) MAXDEV(*FILE) 3) WRITE the format, READ the file.  It doesn't matter how many record formats there are in the display file, in order to take advantage of the time-out, you must follow these rules.  This is different to the way that disk I/O is handled; reading threads on disk I/O won't help with workstation I/O.